# Query posts by meta_key whose value is an array

Tags: query-posts, post-meta

Let's say I'm modifying the default posts query:

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_filter' );

function my_filter( $query ) {

$query->set( 'meta_key', 'my_rating' );
$query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
$query->set( 'order', 'DESC' );

return $query;

}
```

I know this works for the meta_key `my_rating` if its value is a number. But let's say its value is an array whose values are numbers. Like this for example:

```
array(
    "foo" => 1,
    "bar" => 2,
)
```

But the array would be serialized and I guess need to be unserialized to use it. Is there any way to pick which key in the array to sort by?

Answer (score 0):

Your array is a PHP construct and only meaningful to PHP, as far as MySQL is concerned it's just a string of characters. If you need to query on that data it should be separated out into individual keys.

Comment: Thanks for the info. How would I go about separating the data into individual keys? Something like `$data = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_rating', true);` `$number = $data['foo'];` And then `$query->set( 'meta_key', $number );`?